# Message when user changes Business Unit

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a plugin which needs to inform SharePoint whenever a user is added / removed from a team. The plugin is set to trigger on Associate / Disassociate events and it works fine.

However, the plugin does not get triggered when I change the Business Unit. I expected it to be triggered as when I change the BU, the user record is disassociated from the **default team of the old BU** and associated to the **default team of the new BU**.

My plugin is registered on the Associate message.

```
base.RegisteredEvents.Add(new Tuple<int, string, string, Action<LocalPluginContext>>(40, "Associate", "", new Action<LocalPluginContext>(ExecutePostAddUserToTeamInSharePoint)));
```

The plugin is not even triggered.

Is there any other message to which I need to associate my plugin to in order for it to be triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like CRM isn't following its own rules.

I'd register the same plugin on `Post-Operation Update` of `SystemUser` too, adding a comparison of the `businessunitid` between `PreImage` and `PostImage` to see *if* the code should intervene.

(This probably also needs some checking of the `Message` to avoid jumbling up the plugin itself)

Comment: Thanks, yes that works. But it is a bit odd that CRM wouldn't trigger on change of BU!